# RoR: CanCanCan authorize only user created items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancancan

What is wrong with this code? A normal user still being able to see all relatos, when he should only see his own.

My view code:

```erb
<% if can? :read, Relato %>
  <td><%= relato.id %></td>
  <td><%= relato.cliente.name %></td>
  <td><%= relato.projeto.name %></td>
  <td><%= relato.local.logra %></td>
  <td><%= relato.time %></td>
  <td><%= relato.comment %></td>
<% end %>
```

My `Ability` class:

```rb
can :manage, :all if user.role == "admin"

if user.role == "normal"
  can :read, Relato ,  :user_id => user.id 
  can :manage, Relato,  :user_id => user.id 
end
```

Comment: The poor formatting of this code makes it difficult to read, and as a result, assist.

Comment: @BradWerth Mods have approved edits. The code is more readable now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to authorize the user for a *particular* instance:

```
<%= if can? :read, relato %>
```

When you attempt to authorize a user for an entire class, as you do above, CanCanCan ignores any conditions defined in the Ability because it can't determine a `user_id` field for the entire `Relato` model; it can only do so for a single `relato` instance.