# CanCanCan gem: Handling the case where there is no logged in user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, cancan, cancancan

I'm using the [CanCanCan gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/cancancan) (v.12.0) for basic authorization. My `User` model does not use the concept of roles. All I am trying to do is ensure a user is logged in before they can do anything with my main model, `Topic`.

I believe I've written my `Ability` class correctly. My `TopicsController` has an `index` method that, unsurprisingly, displays all of a user's topics.

The issue is that the first `if` in `index.html.erb` is succeeding when there is no logged in user - that doesn't make sense to me. Am I missing something obvious?

```
# ability.rb    
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # default user

    # as long as a user is logged in and owns the topic it can do anything it likes with it
    can [:manage], Topic do |topic|
      !user.new_record? && topic.try(:user) == user
    end
end
```

--

```
# topics_controller.rb
class TopicsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource # CanCanCan gem

  def index
  end
  ...
end
```

--

```
# index.html.erb
<% if can? :read, Topic %>
  <% @topics.each do |topic| %>
    <%# Display all the topics %>
<% else %>
  <%# Handle the case where the user can't read Topics %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [RoR: CanCanCan authorize only user created itens](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31861704/ror-cancancan-authorize-only-user-created-itens)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to authorize the user for a *particular* instance:

```
<%= if can? :read, topic %>
```

When you attempt to authorize a user for an entire class, as you do above, CanCanCan ignores any conditions defined in the Ability because it can't determine a `user` relation for the entire `Topic` model; it can only do so for a single `topic` instance. Unfortunately, AFAIK there's no way to authorize for a relation, so you'll have to either authorize for each instance in the relation.

Alternatively, [in version 1.4](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/authorizing-controller-actions#index-action), `load_and_authorize_resource` in the controller should initialize `@topics` based on the `current_user` only if the Ability is defined *without* blocks. However, its nearly trivial to do this "manually":

```
@topics = current_user.topics
```